# Extract URL from UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am writing a web browser app using UIWebView. I want to be able to save the current URL to a database, just like a bookmark. I have created the standard web browser app such as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpq8r-HHwZA. Any help please with how I can extract the URL address of the current web view. The goal is to have the URL and a user-given name added to a database using CoreData. The "bookmarks" can then be displayed in a UITableView. I have read many similar SO questions but none of the solutions are quite what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set your viewController as the `UIWebView` delegate, then implement a method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  self.currentUrl = webView.request.mainDocumentURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to implement this in a way like, save url when user wants to save/bookmark is so you can implement this like as shown in image below when user press save button then you do whatever you want to do .

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *url = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    // do whatever you want to do with the URL
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works to retrieve the URL, thank you. However, I can only retrieve a search of videos on YT, not the actual video. That is because I have placed the button on a tab bar, but when the video plays it  is full screen only and thus the tab bar can not be seen. I need a button that overlays the video. Do you know of any such solution?